# Got undefined in map result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble converting, summing, and sorting the following arrays into key and value objects

Data Array

```
0: {No: '1', Product Name: 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '120', Url: 'https://harry-potter'}
1: {No: '2', Product Name: 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '100', Url: 'https://harry-potter'}
2: {No: '3', Product Name: 'Naruto', Type: 'Comic', Price: '68', Url: 'https://naruto'}
n: {No: '...', Product Name: '...', Type: '...', Price: '...', Url: '...'}
```

my current code

```
let counts = myRows.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  let count = prev.get(curr["Product Name"]) || 0;
  prev.set(
    curr["Product Name"],
    parseFloat(curr["Product Name"]) + count,
    curr["Url"]
  );
  return prev;
}, new Map());

// then, map your counts object back to an array
let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(([key, value, link]) => {
  return { key, value, link };
});

// SORT BY DESCENDING VALUE
var desc = reducedObjArr.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

console.log(desc);
```

and the result of my current code

```
0:
key: "Harry Potter"
link: undefined
value: 220
1:
key: "Naruto"
link: undefined
value: 68
```

though, the result I want is like this

```
0:
key: "Harry Potter"
link: "https://harry-potter"
value: 220
1:
key: "Naruto"
link: "https://naruto"
value: 68
```

Comment: is it just me or the realisation looks slightly overcomplicated for a relatively easy task?

Comment: The basic problem is that you are calling `set` on a map with 3 arguments.  The 3rd would just be ignored, as it takes a key and value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set)

Comment: Map doesn’t have an indexer. Only get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.prototype.set()` only takes 2 arguments, you're passing 3. If you want to store multiple values in a map key, store them as an array or object. In my code below, I store `[price, url]`.

Another problem is that you were trying to parse `curr["Product Name"]` as the price, but it should be `curr.Price`.

```js
const myRows = [
  {No: '1', "Product Name": 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '120', Url: 'https://harry-potter'},
  {No: '2', "Product Name": 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '100', Url: 'https://harry-potter'},
  {No: '3', "Product Name": 'Naruto', Type: 'Comic', Price: '68', Url: 'https://naruto'}
];

let counts = myRows.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  let count = prev.get(curr["Product Name"])?.[0] || 0;
  prev.set(
    curr["Product Name"], 
    [parseFloat(curr.Price) + count,
      curr.Url
    ]
  );
  return prev;
}, new Map());

// then, map your counts object back to an array
let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(([key, [value, link]]) => {
  return {
    key,
    value,
    link
  };
});

// SORT BY DESCENDING VALUE
var desc = reducedObjArr.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

console.log(desc);
```

Comment: oh so it seems. thanks for the help sir. this is my first time working as a javascript programmer, looks like i need to learn more. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `Map` you could also build a JS object using `reduce()` and in the end use `Object.values()` to get the values as an array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    No: "1",
    "Product Name": "Harry Potter",
    Type: "Novel",
    Price: "120",
    Url: "https://harry-potter",
  },
  {
    No: "2",
    "Product Name": "Harry Potter",
    Type: "Novel",
    Price: "100",
    Url: "https://harry-potter",
  },
  {
    No: "3",
    "Product Name": "Naruto",
    Type: "Comic",
    Price: "68",
    Url: "https://naruto",
  },
];


const result = data.reduce((prev, movie) => {
  // destruct properties for convenience to have shorter name
  const { "Product Name": key, Url: link, Price: value } = movie;
  // parse the value
  const floatValue = parseFloat(value) || 0;
  // use previous value to compute new accumulated value if there is a previous value
  const accValue = prev[key] ? prev[key].value + floatValue: floatValue;
  // set and return new value
  prev[key] = {key: key, link: link, value: accValue};
  return prev;
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: I do agree that author has over-complicated the solution, but you have also over-simplified it, since the output should sum up all the prices of same products (100 + 120, I mean look at the expected output in the question)

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I've edited my answer to reflect that now.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with an [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

1. I would first initialize the value that reduce is going to return to
   an empty array.
2. It would then check if the item already exists in the accumulator.

   1. **If it doesn't exist**, I simply return a new array, with the previous elements in the array and the current iteration value.
   2. **If it exists**, I iterate the accumulator with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a new array, go back and check that the object exists, if it exists I add the current amount of the map iteration to the current amount of the reduce iteration, if it doesn't exist I just return the current value of the iteration within the map.

```js
let myRows = [
    { No: 1, "Product Name": 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '120', Url: 'https://harry-potter' }, 
    { No: 2, "Product Name": 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '100', Url: 'https://harry-potter'},
    { No: 3, "Product Name": 'Naruto', Type: 'Comic', Price: '68', Url: 'https://naruto' }
];

const counts = myRows.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const elementAlreadyExists = accumulator.find(element => element["Product Name"] === currentValue["Product Name"]);
  if (elementAlreadyExists) {
    return accumulator.map((element) => {
      if (element["Product Name"] === currentValue["Product Name"]) {
        return {
          ...element,
          Price: parseFloat(element.Price) + parseFloat(currentValue.Price)
        }
      }
      return element;
    });
  }

  return [...accumulator, currentValue];
}, []);

console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution may achieve the same desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const groupSumSort = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce(
      (fin, itm) => ({
        ...fin,
        [itm["Product Name"]]: (
          fin[itm["Product Name"]]
          ? {
            ...fin[itm["Product Name"]],
            value: fin[itm["Product Name"]].value + +itm.Price
          }
          : { key: itm["Product Name"], link: itm.Url, value: +itm.Price }
        )
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).sort(
    (a, b) => b.value - a.value
  )
);


const myRows = [
  {No: '1', "Product Name": 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '120', Url: 'https://harry-potter'},
  {No: '2', "Product Name": 'Harry Potter', Type: 'Novel', Price: '100', Url: 'https://harry-potter'},
  {No: '3', "Product Name": 'Naruto', Type: 'Comic', Price: '68', Url: 'https://naruto'}
];

console.log(groupSumSort(myRows));
```

**Explanation**

This solution differs from OP's solution in below aspects.

- It considers the `accumulator` named `fin` to be an empty object `{}` initially instead of `new Map()`
- Instead of `.parseFloat`, it uses `+itm.Price` to convert string to number
- Since `fin` is already an object, no need to create a variable: `reducedObjArr`
- The values from `.reduce` contains `key`, `link`, `value` props
- These values are extracted using `Object.values`
- The sorting is done on the values extracted
- The entire logic described above is woven into a method `groupSumSort` to help with readability of the rest of the code